# Javascript "for of" loop not returning value

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
async function getMultiBalances() {
  let chains = await getAllChains();
  let address = await getAddress();
  let totalBalances = [];

  for (let chain of chains) {
    let chainId = chain.chain_id;
    let balances = await getMultichainBalancesArray(chainId, address);
    if (balances != undefined) {
      totalBalances = [...balances, ...totalBalances];
    }
  }
  console.log(totalBalances);
  return totalBalances;
}
```

The above code console logs nothing and returns nothing.

Now.. If I move the console log and return statement into the "for of" loop it will return the first iteration and work fine. I don't understand why I can't return the final value outside of the for of loop to get the array I actually want.

```
async function getMultiBalances() {
  let chains = await getAllChains();
  let address = await getAddress();
  let totalBalances = [];

  for (let chain of chains) {
    let chainId = chain.chain_id;
    let balances = await getMultichainBalancesArray(chainId, address);
    if (balances != undefined) {
      totalBalances = [...balances, ...totalBalances];
    }
    console.log(totalBalances);
    return totalBalances;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you see if you put `console.log(balances)` into the loop, but keep `return` outside the loop?

Comment: Does `getMultichainBalancesArray` ever resolve?

Comment: seems that `getMultichainBalancesArray` doesn't always resolve.  The first time, yes, but not every time

Comment: If I log inside the loop, it logs the correct array I want.

No, it doesn't resolve and I don't know how to make it resolve.

Comment: Then clearly the problem is nothing to do with `for...of` but with whatever `getMultichainBalancesArray` does. Which you've not shown.

Comment: I think it's working fine as it functions as expected when I console log inside the for...of loop.